# A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required

Tags: 16.04, command-line, dotnet

Im quite new to Ubuntu and have been stuck on this for a few days now. Ive been trying to run a dll via dotnet but each time I launch I get a "fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so'  required to execute the application was not found in '/root/duo/'.
I did a

```
 sudo updatedb && locate hostpolicy.so | xargs sha1sum
```

and got

```
 1c51298979874c5ff0e30798406760c77bea7adc  /root/sdk/1.0.4/libhostpolicy.so
 a930b639bf61b038869d69aea1e773648f77a7c4  /root/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0.5/libhostpo                     licy.so
 1c51298979874c5ff0e30798406760c77bea7adc  /root/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.2/libhostpo                     licy.so
 dd784807e436e626a7a223d8b8010c537f01b6a5  /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/libhostpolicy.so
 93c2979d35dd12c6eb516e742af3ccc5c9504438  /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.0                     .5/libhostpolicy.so
 dd784807e436e626a7a223d8b8010c537f01b6a5  /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1                     .2/libhostpolicy.so
 28998aec4bb7bf1b592ba34de4ffb280249c073f  /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.0                     .0/libhostpolicy.so
```

How to I get to make the said library be seen ? Do I have any conflict issues as I had tried to overcome dotnet compatibility issues before. Thanks

Comment: any updates on this one ?